# Por que mesmo encontrando o "valor" no if o Python da também o print do else?

Tags: python, algoritmo, if

Usando esse código reparei que quando coloco o operador, mesmo que seja algum dos que citei, por exemplo `*`, o resultado final do *run* é o valor multiplicado e em seguida o da soma, que é o que indiquei no `else` (`a + b`) caso a escolha não fosse nenhum dos outros operadores.

```
a=int(input('digite um número:'))
b=int(input('digite outro número:'))

c=(input("escolha a operação que deseja: / para dividir, * para multiplicar - para subtrair e + para somar: "))

while c != "/" and c!= "*" and c!= "-" and c!= "+":

   c=(input("digite um operador válido"))

if c == "/":

      print (a/b)

if c == "*":

      print(a*b)

if c == "-":

      print(a-b)

else:

      print(a+b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando você tem os `if`s isolados eles não são excludentes, a avaliação é feita em cada um. Se um deles tem um `else` ele vai tentar ver aquilo.

Então no seu exemplo o último `if` verifica se `c` é o sinal de `-`, e se for ele faz uma subtração. E tem um `else`, ou seja, se `c` não for igual a `-` ele faz soma. Se você digitar `*` então `c` não é `-`, e portanto ele faz a soma.

Se quer que eles sejam excludentes precisa fazer com que se uma coisa só, ou seja, precisa usar `elif` para um novo `if` ser o `else` do anterior e assim agrupa como algo único e só um deles será executado.

Algo assim:

```
a = int(input('digite um número:'))
b = int(input('digite outro número:'))
c = (input("escolha a operação que deseja: / para dividir, * para multiplicar - para subtrair e + para somar: "))
while c != "/" and c != "*" and c != "-" and c != "+":
    c = (input("digite um operador válido"))
if c == "/":
    print (a / b)
elif c == "*":
    print(a * b)
elif c == "-":
    print(a - b)
else:
    print(a + b)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/n4BPnf). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/dkyjhttehd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/Calculator.py).